# rhandsontable writing NULL values to SQL database using dbWriteTable

Tags: r, sql-server, ssms, rhandsontable

I'm creating the following table using library(rhandsontable)

```
rhandsontable(df, className = "htCenter", stretchH = "all", columnSorting = TRUE) %>%
         hot_col("Date", type = "date", dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD") %>%
         hot_cols(format = '1')
```

The table is converted to a data frame `dfHot <- hot_to_r(input$hot)` and then copied to a SSMS SQL database with

```
dbWriteTable(con, "TEST", dfHot, append = TRUE, overwrite = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

The problem is the table can contain `NULL` values which appear as `NA` in R, but I need them to come across as `NULL` into SQL.

I'm getting this error when `NA` values are present in the table:

> Warning: Error in .local: execute JDBC update query failed in
>   dbSendUpdate (The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure
>   call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 6 (""): The
>   supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the
>   source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data
>   of numeric type with scale greater than precision.)

If no `NA` values are present, the table imports without any issues.

Comment: I found this related post, but still doesn't seem there is an answer when using library(RJDBC):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598952/dbwritetable-cannot-write-nulls-into-sql-server-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `dbWriteTable`, I resolved this issue by inserting the VALUES into SQL. Details found here: https://www.pmg.com/blog/insert-r-data-frame-sql%EF%BB%BF/

Comment: Link now 404's.